# Перевод MAC адреса из string в u_char[]

Tags: c++, парсер

Подскажите как правильно перевести строку string с MAC адресом имеющую формат:

```
FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

в массив типа

```
u_char mac[6] = {"0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF"};
```

Answer (score 0):

есть много-много способов. Если формат макадреса только такой (а это легко проверить по длине и наличию двоеточий, то все просто

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  mac[i] = std::stoi(addr.substr(i*3,2), nullptr, 16);
}
```

Второй способ - через scanf - [пример на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553805/how-to-convert-a-mac-address-in-string-to-array-of-integers).

И мой любимый способ

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string ReplaceAll(std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length(); // Handles case where 'to' is a substring of 'from'
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::string mac = "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF";

    std::string r = "u_char mac[6] = {\"" + ReplaceAll(mac, ":", "\", \"0x") + "\"};";
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

и потом через компилятор прогнать:)

Comment: не один способ не подошел?